# Encoded apostrophe is converted to %27

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, encoding, uri

I want to access the following link:

```
http://localhost:8080/lookups/TagGroup.html?
    is_guideline_tag=true&field_name=%3C%3Ealert('1')%3E&tag_group_id=38
```

but when I paste it into the browser (Chrome 63.0.3239.84) it becomes:

```
http://localhost:8080/lookups/TagGroup.html?
    is_guideline_tag=true&field_name=%3C%3Ealert(%271%27)%3E&tag_group_id=38
```

so the apostrophes are replaced by `%27` and I can't access the link.

I want also to mention that field_name in my above link is obtained like this: `encodeURIComponent("<>alert('1')>")` which should return `%3C%3Ealert('1')%3E`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is there code in a parameter? That's quite a security risk...

Comment: `field_name=<>alert(**'1'**)>` ? What?

Comment: Actually field_name=<>alert('1')>. The asterisks should embrace the bold text, because I wanted to emphasise where the issue appears.

Answer (score 8):

> so the apostrophes are replaced by %27 and I can't access the link

`%27` is the correct, up-to-date way to include `'` in a URI-encoded string (the query string in a URL is URI-encoded). If you're having trouble with it server-side, it sounds like you're not URI-decoding properly. That's what you need to fix. Your field is just fine if you URI-decode it:

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent('%3C%3Ealert(%271%27)%3E'));
```

I don't know specifically why Chrome encodes `'` to `%27`, just that it's valid to do so. I thought it was because Chrome implemented the up-to-date [RFC 3986 definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), which includes `'` as a reserved character which must be encoded, but it isn't consistent about that (`'` is in the category `sub-delims` which includes other characters like `!` which Chrome leaves alone). [`encodeURIComponent` uses](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-uri-syntax-and-semantics) the outdated [RFC 2396 definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.2), which does not list `'` as a reserved character. I assume the Chromium project had a reason for converting `'` to `%27`. But again, it's valid and in the resulting URL the `%27` represents a `'`.

(You also be wondering why `decodeURIComponent` decodes `%27` if `encodeURIComponent` doesn't encode it. It's because *all* encoded entities are decoded, not just select ones. `%nn` where nn is two hex digits always defines an encoded entity that should be decoded, regardless of whether it had to be encoded originally.)

---

I assume you're being **very** careful with what you do with that code in the query string as well...

Comment: Is this really the case? 1. Chrome only encodes `'` and none of the other reserved characters. 2. RFC3986 defines allowable query characters as `*( pchar / "/" / "?" )` where pchar includes `'`

Comment: @Hurelu - Thanks! Yeah, I don't understand why Chrome changes `'` but not, say, `!`, as both are in `sub-delims`. I'm sure they have a reason. I've adjusted the answer.